# remove list of strings from string column in R

Tags: r, string, dataframe

I have a dataframe like so:

```
df = data.frame('name' = c('California parks', 'bear lake', 'beautiful tree house', 'banana plant'), 'extract' = c('parks', 'bear', 'tree', 'plant'))
```

How do I remove the strings of the 'extract' column from the name column to get the following result:

```
name_new = California, lake, beautiful house, banana
```

I'm suspecting this demands a combination of `str_extract`  and `lapply` but can quite figure it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `str_remove` or `str_replace` are vectorized for both `string` and `pattern`.  So, if we have two columns, just pass those columns 'name', 'extract' as the `string`, `pattern` to remove the substring in the 'name' column elementwise.  Once we remove those substring, there are chances of having spaces before or after which can be removed or replaced with `str_replace` with `trimws` (to remove the leading/lagging spaces)

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
df %>% 
    mutate(name_new = str_remove(name, extract),
        name_new = str_replace_all(trimws(name_new), "\\s{2,}", " "))
#                 name extract        name_new
#1     California parks   parks      California
#2            bear lake    bear            lake
#3 beautiful tree house    tree beautiful house
#4         banana plant   plant          banana
```

Answer (score 2):

A base R option using `gsub` + `Vectorize`

```
within(df,name_new <- Vectorize(gsub)(paste0("\\s",extract,"\\s")," ",name))
```

which gives

```
                  name extract        name_new
1     California parks   parks      California
2            bear lake    bear            lake
3 beautiful tree house    tree beautiful house
4         banana plant   plant          banana
```